# Applescript email

Tags: macos, applescript

I have been messing around with applescript for the last week or so and i'm wondering if its possible to attach applescript to an email somehow so that it runs when the email is opened. It might not be possible but I am just wondering if it is, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think its possible to auto run an applescript file when someone opens an email. But the user can manually open the file and run it.